# How to combine multiple "Collect Statistics" statement in openquery

Tags: sql-server-2008, teradata

I'd like to combine multiple "Collect Statistics" after insert statement when execute openquery on SqlServer to Teradata.  Is there a way to do it? I am not able to find an answer online.  Here is an example:

EXEC ('INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE2; 
COLLECT STATISTICS ON  TABLE1 INDEX ( IDX1,IDX2);
COLLECT STATISTICS ON  TABLE1 INDEX ( IDX3);') AT [linkserver];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COLLECT STATS` is a DDL-statement and must be immediately commited, there's no way to run multiple collects in a Multi Statement Request.

But you can simply collect multiple stats in a single collect, this should work:

```
EXEC ('INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE2; 
       COLLECT STATISTICS INDEX ( IDX1,IDX2), INDEX ( IDX3) ON TABLE1;') AT [linkserver];
```

Comment: Hi Diater, when I combined insert and collect together in one openquery like above, I got this error "Data definition not valid unless solitary".  Is "collect" not allowed with DML statement in openquery?  However, I got to add multiple indexes in one statement like you showed me above which is great.

Comment: @angelcake: Ops, I forgot, you can't mix DML & DDL within a MultiStatement, you need two seperate EXECs.

Comment: Thank you Diaeter!  I separated DML & DDL in two EXECs and I was able to add multiple index for one table.